# Android Jetpack compose (1.0.0-beta07): TextField - None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I started working with Jetpack compose (1.0.0-beta07) and I ran into a pretty strange problem with TextField. According to all possible documentation and instructions, I do everything right, but Android Studio constantly writes me the message `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.` for `TextField`

Below is my written code, where Studio still underlines `Text (label)` and `text = it`, but I take it that it has a problem defining `TextField`. The problem disappears when I replace `remember {mutableStateOf ("text")}` with `"text"`, but `TextField` does not change the text when typing the keyboard.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType

@Composable
fun SimpleTextField(label: String = "Label", key: String = "unknown", keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text){
    var text = remember {
        mutableStateOf("text")
    }

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
        },
        label = { Text(label) },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = keyboardType)
    )
}
```

[image: Image of error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
var text = remember { mutableStateOf("text") }

TextField(
    value = text.value,
    onValueChange = {
        text.value = it
    },
    label = { Text(label) },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = keyboardType)
)
```

or:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("text") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    label = { Text(label) },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = keyboardType)
)
```

You can read more info about the [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html) in the official doc.

Comment: This solution is what I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is still present: 
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Text") }

TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { value ->
                text = value
            },
            label = Text("Label"),
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
        )

Comment: Compose 1.0.0-rc02

Comment: This is still a known issue in 2023.  Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error.
And I change the build.gradle.kts file imports and activity imports. Its work fine now.

in graddle I add the:

```
dependencies {
    val composeVersion = "1.4.2"
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion")
}
```

In activity or composable file Text import should be like:

```
import androidx.compose.material.Text
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check some parameters for example color is using material3 in the latest version so they need the parameter according to that

in my case, this line is causing errors in the field

```
    colors = MaterialTheme.color scheme.background
```

so I replace it with the below one

```
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and resolved it by adding `@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)` above the Compose function.